# git pull --rebase fork infomation

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-pull

We are using `git pull --rebase` instead of `git pull`. We have a problem retrieving the fork information that doesn't show anymore on the server.

Assume a single "master" branch from which people push and pull.
Also, assume people modified different files and there was no conflict raised by git.

Here is an image of my local branch and its upstream before the pull

```
      A---B---C local
     /
D---E---F---G server
```

If we were using `git pull` (the standard one) this is what would have happened

```
      A---B---C 
     /         \
D---E---F---G---M---
```

but since we are using `git pull --rebase` this is what happens if I am not wrong:

```
D---E---F---G---A'--B'--C'
```

Now we know that one of the tests doesn't work anymore in C'. We are sure it was working in both C and G. Even if there was no conflicts, This could have possibly happened, if there was two redundant code blocks, and the first guy removed one block while the other guy removed the other block.

Normally the modifications to be checked are those in the commits A',B',C,F,G, because the fork has happened at E. But since we are using `git pull --rebase` we can not know when the fork has happened so we are unable to recognize the set A',B',C,F,G.

1) Knowing that the problem now only appears at C' is there a way to recognize E and hence the set A',B',C,F,G ?

2) If the answer to 1) is "no" then what commits should be checked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR: you can find commit `E` using `git merge-base` and reflog information.

---

Your drawing is correct, because what rebase does is *copy* commits (to new, slightly different ones).

The original commits remain in the repository for some time (30 days in general, by default): they are just placed out of view.  It's possible (using the reflogs and/or `ORIG_HEAD` to find the original `C` and from there, the merge-base commit `E`.

If this sort of thing happens often, though, I'd suggest not using `git pull` directly.  In fact, I recommend never *starting* with `git pull`, even though it takes a bit more work, and more typing, to use the two separate underlying steps.  The idea here is to make it obvious what Git is doing, and hence make it easier to plug in useful automation.  (Afterward, depending on your own automation, you can go back to using `git pull`, with or without `--rebase`, if you find it more convenient to run one command instead of two.)

What `git pull` does is run `git fetch`, and then either `git merge` or `git rebase`.  While `pull` has a few additional bells and whistles, this really is the heart of its action.  The nice thing about doing these two separately is that they let you inspect the state after the `fetch` and before the `merge`-or-`rebase`.

(This is far less necessary with `merge` since the "before merge" state is bleeding obvious: just peel away the merge commit and you have the before-merge state.  It's more useful with `rebase` since the "before merge" state lets you view both sides of the forked development separately if you wish, before allowing Git to do its wild and crazy thing, making copies of commits.)

Let's reproduce your "before" state here, and then show what rebase really did.  Here is the "before" state, which you will have after running `git fetch`, but before running `git rebase`:

```
      A---B---C   <-- HEAD -> branch
     /
D---E---F---G     <-- origin/branch
```

I added the name `HEAD` pointing to your current branch, and renamed the branches a bit to be more typical.

After the `git rebase` step, we have this:

```
      A---B---C            <-- ORIG_HEAD, branch@{1}
     /
D---E---F---G              <-- origin/branch
             \
              A'--B'--C'   <-- HEAD -> branch
```

Normally, viewers (`git log`, `gitk --all`, and so on) skip over the special references like `ORIG_HEAD`, `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`, and so on.  They also ignore the contents of the reflogs (`branch@{1}`).  Using `git reflog` or `git log -g`, or adding names like `ORIG_HEAD` on the command line, you can instruct these viewers to show you the originals.

If you separate the two steps, it's easy to save information about, or add markers (such as temporary `git tag`s) to, any particular commits.  For instance, after `git fetch`, you can mark commit `E`: find the<sup>1</sup> merge base of `branch` and `origin/branch`, and mark it:

```
$ git tag temp-marker $(git merge-base branch origin/branch)
```

(assuming sh or bash or similar; note that to generalize this, you can just use `HEAD` and `@{u}` in place of `branch` and `origin/branch`).

Make sure to delete the `temp-marker` tag (or at least avoid pushing it) if you don't want to confuse people ("why is there a tag named `temp-marker` in all our repositories?!"), once you are done with it.

Even if you do use `git pull --rebase` to keep them combined, you can, afterwards, use the reflog and/or `ORIG_HEAD` to do the same.  (The main problem here is that both the number in the reflog—`branch@{1}` above—and `ORIG_HEAD` itself get updated.  If you do another rebase, `ORIG_HEAD` now tracks *that* rebase instead of the one you are still concerned with.  Meanwhile if you make any update to `branch`, the number (`@{1}`) increments: now you need `branch@{2}`, then `branch@{3}`, and so on.  (You can also use `branch@{yesterday}`, which checks the date-stamp on each change recorded to `branch`, and uses the latest one that is from "yesterday".  See [the `git reflog` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html) and its link back to [`git log`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html), and also [`gitrevisions`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), for details.)

In other words, once you are in this particular pickle, check whether `branch@{1}` is the right reference (or `ORIG_HEAD` is still good).  If not, use `git reflog` or similar to find the right reference.  In any case, once you have found it:

```
git merge-base branch@{1} origin/branch
```

will locate commit `E`.

---

<sup>1</sup>This assumes there is only one merge base commit.  For all of the cases we are considering here, that should be true.  You get multiple merge bases only in the presence of "criss-cross merges" (which must be made by hand):

```
...--o--*---o--o   <-- branch1
         \ /
          X
         / \
...--o--*---o--o   <-- branch2
```

Here, there is no single merge base between `branch1` and `branch2`: both `*` commits are suitable merge bases.  This cannot occur in normal workflows with a single branch-with-upstream (because you cannot check out `origin/branch` and make commits on it).  You would have to do some of your own wild and crazy things (using a temporary branch, two explicit merges, and at least one push) to make it happen.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this instructive answer. I wish I could up vote you 100 times.